# NameAndIdProvider não encontra referencia no contexto da classe - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Preciso fazer uma implementação customizada para o campo de input, portanto criei a seguinte classe:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "tm-for", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class TmInputTagHelper : InputTagHelper
{
    
    public TmInputTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {            
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("tm-for")]
    public ModelExpression TmFor
    {
        get => For;
        set => For = value;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);


        string fullName = NameAndIdProvider.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ViewContext, For.Name);

        if (ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out var entry) && entry.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            output.AddClass("is-invalid", HtmlEncoder.Default);
            output.RemoveClass("input-validation-error", HtmlEncoder.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Porem, não consigo achar a referencia para esta classe: NameAndIdProvider:

```
string fullName = NameAndIdProvider.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ViewContext, For.Name);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho os seguintes usings:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
```

Bem, já não sei como consigo ultrapassar isso!

Comment: essa classe é `internal` e não está disponível para programação. exemplo da implementação da classe: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/NameAndIdProvider.cs

Comment: o que a variavel `fullname` faz? tem um erro no codigo também na base `base.process` tem que verificar aonde deve ficar!